# Redis data structure design for inbox

Tags: data-structures, redis

My website allows users to communicate using conversations.

In the conversation-inbox page a user can see all the users that have contacted him, including a preview of the latest message from the specific user. The page is order by the date of the previewed message.

It looks roughly something like this:

```
UserA "Some message.."  2016-3-3
UserB "Other message.." 2016-3-2
UserC "..."             2016-2-15
etc..
```

I was wondering what is the correct combination of the Redis data structures to use to model this efficiently.

At first I thought about having a sorted set of the users (i.e. UserA, UserB, UserC), but this would mean I would have to have a loop to get the latest message from each user.

Is there a better way, avoiding the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not keep a Sorted Set of message post user, with all the messages in her inbox from other users?

Comment: If I understand your suggestion right, because I only want to show the latest message from each user. Say for example the userX in question has 1000 messages from UserA send after the 1 message from UserB. I will have to traverse the 999 messages, just to discard them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need two data structures for each user's inbox: a Hash and a Sorted Set.

The Sorted Set's scores can be all set to 0 as we'll be using lexicographical ordering anyway (but there's no harm in setting them to the actual timestamp of the message, at least in the context of this answer). The members of the Sorted Set should be constructed in the following manner:

```
<date in YYYYMMDD>:<from user>:<message>
```

This will let you easily pull that view and page through it with [`ZREVRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange).

But that's only half of the story - when  userX is sent a new message from  userA, you'll need some way of finding and removing userA's previous message from userX's inbox - that's why you need the Hash.

The Hash is used for looking up the latest message from a given user to userX. For each of userX's friends, keep in the Hash a field that is the sending user's ID (e.g. userA) and whose value is the inbox's Sorted Set member that represents the latest message from that user (same "syntax" as above). When a new message arrives, first fetch the previous message from the Hash, remove it from the Set, and then add the new message to the Set and update the Hash's field.

To make sure that Hash and Sorted Set are consistent, I recommend that you look into wrapping them together in a transaction. You can use a [`MULTI/EXEC` block](http://redis.io/topics/transactions), but my preference is a Lua script.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for.